# Unused variable error when my variable is definitely being used

Tags: c++, file, file-io, filestream

If there is no filename provided, I want to use a default. Or, if a filename is provided but the file can't be accessed, use default.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    // default settings
    bool flag = false;
    string fileName = "defaultMap.txt";
    ifstream *infile = new ifstream(fileName);

    if (argc > 1) {
        fileName = argv[i]; // otherwise, it is a file name
        flag = true;
        delete infile;
        ifstream *infile = new ifstream(fileName);

        //if file is not valid: 
        if (!infile->good() || infile->fail()) { 
            cout << "Problem loading board from map file \'" << fileName << "\'." << endl;
            delete infile;
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    if (!flag) ifstream *infile = new ifstream("defaultMap.txt"); //change back to default

    Board * grid = new Board(*infile, playerRace, flag);

    // MORE STUFF FOR MAIN HERE
}
```

Then, I send the file into a function which reads it character by character to fill a matrix. Board() is only called once, whereas boardInit is called every time the player goes into a new room, and more information needs to be read from the file.

```
Board::Board(ifstream & fileName, string race, bool flag) {
  player = new Player(race);
  boardInit(fileName, race, flag);
}



void Board::boardInit(ifstream & fileName, string race, bool flag) {

    char cell;
    game = new Cell*[maxRow];
    for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
        game[row] = new Cell[maxCol];
        for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
            fileName.get(cell);
        }
    }
      // MORE STUFF FOR boardINIT here
}
```

When I try to compile I get the error

```
main.cc:122:23: error: unused variable 'infile' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
        if (!flag) ifstream *infile = new ifstream("defaultMap.txt"); //change back to default
                             ^
1 error generated.
```

even though I am passing it to Board right below (`Board * grid = new Board(*infile, playerRace, flag);`)

Comment: try changing `ifstream *infile = ...` to `infile = ...`

Comment: Firstly, stop using `new` unless you have a good reason, which you don't have in your code. Secondly, C++ has nested scopes and a variable name only has to be unique within its scope. Imagine curly braces on that if condition if it still isn't clear. Lastly, your question is off-topic, because you haven't reduced it to the smalles amount of code showing the problem. That probably would have given you the right idea yourself without asking.

Comment: @momo Why not make that into an answer, explaining what is going on?

Comment: @juanchopanza i've posted an answer, it conflicts with another one. could you please verify its correctness?

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding your previous variable with the same name.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    // default settings
    bool flag = false;
    string fileName = "defaultMap.txt";
    ifstream *infile = new ifstream(fileName); // <-------------- HERE
```

See? You defined it first a bit above and then, you don't use it inside the if statement because you create a new variable with this name which *hides* `infile` in the top of main. Thus the `infile` inside the if statement has it's lifetime expired at the end of `if (!flag)` scope so it will no longer exist and your `infile` variable from the top will be visible again:

```
if (!flag) ifstream *infile = new ifstream("defaultMap.txt"); //change back to default
```

To use your previous variable simply don't hide it with the declaration of new variable, just use previous:

```
if (!flag) infile = new ifstream("defaultMap.txt"); //change back to default
```

Also:

- Consider to change `"defaultMap.txt"` to a string constant:

  ```
  static const string defaultFileName = "defaultMap.txt";
  string fileName = defaultFileName;

  // ... and later:

  if (!flag) infile = new ifstream(defaultFileName); //change back to default
  ```
- Consider to use smart pointers because it is 2016 already. Look at [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
- Consider just to review your own code, you have a lot of refactoring to be done here which will greatly simplify your code and make it easier to read and understand for people.

Comment: I see. If I eliminate the news as someone suggested, i.e. use `ifstream infile = ifstream(fileName);` instead, do I have to do anything (such as making it a pointer) when passing to board? Since board accepts `ifstream & file`. Or do I have to change board?

Comment: Also, thank you for the link. Good thing I can read russian lol

Comment: *"You defined it first a bit above and then, you don't use it because you create a new variable with this name which hides infile in the main."* The unused variable is the one defined in the `if (!flag)` line. You later explain that correctly, but the statement I quoted has it back to front.

Comment: @user5759490 Simple: initialize an `ifstream` with the right filename: `ifstream inFile(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "defaultMap.txt");`

Comment: you keep writing `*infile` when you mean `infile`

Comment: I am confused about how I should be storing and passing these streams. Yes, I wrote infile now, so does that mean that when I pass it to board, the board parameter type should just be infile? Not the address? Isn't that bad because it's copy the file every time and wasting space?

Comment: @user5759490 You need to read up on references and basic C++ in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this particular piece of code

```
if (!flag) {
    ifstream *infile = new ifstream("defaultMap.txt");
}
```

`infile` defined here has scope only with curly braces. If you try to use it beyond curly braces, it won't be visible. In your case, when you use `infile` after this section, you are actually using same-name variable declared at top. So effectively, `infile` defined in this block is not used hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the warning because in case the `if` condition evaluates to `false`, the variable will not be declared and will hence be *unused*. You have already declared it, so omit the `ifstream` and change it to `infile = new ifstream(filename);`